# Proving that an integral related to order statistics is increasing in a certain parameter

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, integration

Let $f$ and $F$ denote, respectively, the pdf and cdf of a probability distribution on $\mathbb R$. Take any natural $n\ge3$ and any real $a$ and $c$ such that $a\le c$.

Does it always follow that
$$
\int_{a}^{c}e^{\rho(b-a)}F(b)^{n-3}\left[  (n-1)F(b)-(n-2)F(c)\right]  f(b)db
$$
is nondecreasing in $\rho\ge0$? 
(The displayed integral is related to order statistics.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. The derivative in $\rho$ of the integral in question can be written as 
\begin{equation}
 J:=\int_{a}^{c}G(b)h(b)\,db, 
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 G(b):=(b-a)e^{\rho(b-a)},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
 h(b):=F(b)^{n-3}\left[  (n-1)F(b)-(n-2)F(c)\right]  f(b). 
\end{equation}
It is enough to show that $J\ge0$.

Clearly, there is some $b_*\in[a,c]$ such that 
$h(b)\le0$ for $b\in[a,b_*)$ and $h(b)\ge0$ for $b\in[b_*,c]$. 
Moreover, the function $G$ is increasing, for each $\rho\ge0$. 
Therefore, 
\begin{equation}
 J=\int_{[a,b_*)}G(b)h(b)\,db+\int_{[b_*,c]}G(b)h(b)\,db
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
 \ge \int_{[a,b_*)}G(b_*)h(b)\,db+\int_{[b_*,c]}G(b_*)h(b)\,db
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
 =G(b_*)\int_{[a,c]}h(b)\,db
 =G(b_*)F(a)^{n-2}[F(c)-F(a)]\ge0, 
\end{equation}
as desired.